# Twitter Bootstrap Framework and Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap

I know it is very new but has anyone started using Twitter's Bootstrap Framework with Zend Framework?

I can figure out the basic stuff like getting bootstrap working with my layout pages but how do I use some of the bootstrap form calls with Zend_Form?

Just looking for a place to start with this.

Any help with this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an project called EasyBib_Form_Decortators, small library to use Bootstrap with Zend Form.

It works like a charme, ok some bugs with the "MessageFormatter" View Helper but ok :-)

[Easybib](https://github.com/easybib/EasyBib_Form_Decorator)

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to start and found this as well:
http://zf-boilerplate.com/

It looks really promising. Haven't spent much time with it though.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few repositories on Github that do exactly that, the one i stuck with so far is:

https://github.com/komola/Bootstrap-Zend-Framework

It did the trick for me so far, though i lately noticed an incompatibility with ZF Version 1.12

This looks like a promising alternative, which i am gonna give a try soon:

https://github.com/Emagister/zend-form-decorators-bootstrap